# VS Code Jupyter Ctrl + / does not comment out the selected code block

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, comments, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook of Visual Studio Code for Windows,

Ctrl + / with the code selected used to comment out the selected code.

But it does not work suddenly and shows a dropdown menu such as '/BOOTNXT' that I have never seen.

The keyboard shortcut setting has not been changed as in the 3rd screenshot.

What should be the problem here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The comment-block shortcut has always been Ctrl+Shift+/, as far as I know. The comment-line shortcut is Ctrl+K,Ctrl+/. This is for Visual Studio, not Code.